# Can goals in Google Analytics be backdated after the goal's URL changed?

Tags: google-analytics, goals

We've redesigned our site, and the single goal URL that we used became out of date.
We forgot to update it, but have done so now.

We see that the goals for this month are still zero. Therefore, I assume that updating a goal URL does not backdate the goal total for hits to that URL?

For example:

Original goal URL:

> /mysite.com/goal.html

After redesign, *actual URL*:

> /mysite.com/cart/goal.html

Time elapses and *actual URL* is hit, then goal URL updated to:

> /mysite.com/cart/goal.html

We hoped that it would update the goal totals, as the URLs are still visible in other statistics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't backdate your goals, but you may be able try a "Search and replace" filter of the URL. More info on that can be found [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034834?hl=en).

It would look something like:

```
Search string: /goal\.html
Replace string: /cart/goal\.html
```

Comment: Thanks for that.  I'm not too bothered about search/replace, but the important fact is that the goals cannot be backdated, so thanks for the confirmation.